# Show that $f(z) = |z|^2$ has no primitive.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the function $f : \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $f(z) = |z|^2 ,$ $z \in \mathbb C$ has no primitive.

**My attempt** $:$

If $f$ has a primitive then $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz$$ will be the same over any contour $\gamma$ with the same initial and terminal point.

Now if we take two polygons $\gamma_{1} : \gamma_{1} = [1,i]$ and $\gamma_{2} : \gamma_{2} = [1,1+i,i]$ then though the initial and terminal points of $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ are the same $$\int_{\gamma_{1}} f(z)\ dz = \frac {2(i-1)} {3} \neq \frac {4(i-1)} {3} = \int_{\gamma_{2}} f(z)\ dz$$.

Hence the function $f$ has no primitive.

Is the above reasoning correct at all.Please verify it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct but the argument is simpler if you evaluate the integral of $|z|^2$ along the counterclockwise closed curve $C$ given by the unit upper semi-circle centred at $0$ and the segment $[-1,1]$:
$$\int_{C} |z|^2\ dz=\int_0^{\pi }1\cdot d(e^{it}) +\int_{-1}^1 t^2\ dt
=[e^{it}]_0^{\pi}+[t^3/3]_{-1}^1=-2-\frac{2}{3}=-\frac{8}{3}.$$
If $|z|^2$ has a primitive then the above integral should be equal.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Z for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: But $\int_{|z|=1} 1\,dz = 0$, so this doesn't suffice.

Comment: @mrf Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If it would have a primitive $F(z)$, then $F(z)$ would be holomorphic. But the derivative of an holomorphic function is holomorphic, then $f$ would be holomorphic, which is not true.